# Multi-threaded RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, message-queue, channel

I am working on a simple worker micro-service in Java, which is consuming (basicConsume) messages from RMQ, processing them and inserting them into a DB.
Currently, the service is using 1 thread for the whole flow.

My task is to refactor it to use multiple threads when inserting data into the DB.

This is my idea for the design:
[image: ![worker service flow]

As you can see, I am using the main thread in order to consume messages and push them into a queue.
By the end of the flow, I am pushing the DB responses into another queue and acknowlesging each one of them from from another thread.

Following my investigation, if the same Channel is used for consumption and acknowledge, those operations are thread-safe. I am having trouble to understand how can I improve the communication with RMQ and if another Channel can help. As the documantation says, the Channel consumed a message has to be the Channel which acknowledging it.

My question is regarding the idea of this design:

1. WDYT about the messaging queue idea?
2. Should I use another thread to consume those messages and push them into the queue?
3. If the answer for 2. is yes, should I use the same Channel for both of the threads?
4. When I am using the same Channel for the acknowledges, is it going to affect the efficiency of the consumptions? my intuition says that while the Channel is used for acknowledging, the Channel can't be used for consuming. Am I right?